# Group a set of SCNNode in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

Is there a way to group a set of unrelated SCNNode (the nodes are not parent/child of each other) together? And if yes, is there a way to ungroup them?

I would like to group a set of SCNNode together to perform an operation (says rotation, movement).

Comment: Wouldn't it just be the matter of naming nodes wisely?

Comment: You mean the way to do that is to name all related nodes the same name? This seem reasonable, but the nodes are selected by user.

Comment: That doesn't ring me a bell as to what your issue is.